# ASCII Character to Decimal Value in R

Tags: r, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Given a word I need to find the decimal values of each letter in that word and store it in an array.
I used `strtoi` function to achieve this. But later found out below two functions which are supposed to give same output are giving different result. Can anyone explain why?

1st attempt

```
> strtoi("d",16L)
[1] 13
```

2nd attempt

```
> strtoi(charToRaw("d"),16L)
[1] 100
```

And what does `16L` in the base of `srtoi` mean? I am fairly new to Dec, Hex, Oct representation of ASCII characters. So please share some information about it.

Comment: *For a base greater than 10, letters a to z (or A to Z) are used to represent 10 to 35.* - from `?strtoi`.  And `charToRaw("d")` evaluates to 64, so in the second you would be doing `strtoi(64, 16L)`.  Not sure why you think they would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

For illustration purposes only:

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

input_str <- "Alphabet."

charToRaw(input_str) %>%
  map_df(~data_frame(letter=rawToChar(.),
                     hex_value=toString(.),
                     decimal_value=as.numeric(.)))
## # A tibble: 9 × 3
##   letter hex_value decimal_value
##    <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>
## 1      A        41            65
## 2      l        6c           108
## 3      p        70           112
## 4      h        68           104
## 5      a        61            97
## 6      b        62            98
## 7      e        65           101
## 8      t        74           116
## 9      .        2e            46
```

Since what you need to do can be done all in base R:

```
as.numeric(charToRaw(input_str))
## [1]  65 108 112 104  97  98 101 116  46
```

You can also do `as.integer()` vs `as.numeric()` if you just need/want integers.